# Hide/remove the GridViewGroupRow in Telerik RadGridView WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik-grid

How to Hide/remove the GridViewGroupRow (RowHeader with Expand/Collapse) in Telerik RadGridView WPF.

I tried to set Height=1 Or Visibility=Collapsed but it hides the data (not RowHeader).

```
       <telerik:RadGridView.GroupRowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewGroupRow">
                <Setter Property="ShowHeaderAggregates" Value="False"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </telerik:RadGridView.GroupRowStyle>
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Note :

- I can able to hide the Expand/Collapse Button & other Aggregation Contents.
- I can able to hide the indent cell Columns of GridView.

But unable to hide the GridViewGroupRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Setting the height as zero in telerik's indentpresenter style solves the problem.

And also we can style every indent portion seperately.

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radgridview-styling-indent-cells.html